# List Variables - Express JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server

I'm trying to debug some code which I would like to access a list of all the global variables my express server has stored;- but im not sure how to do it without using the keys(window) method which only works for browsers. Any ideas?

`object(keys) console.log(keys) keys(window)`

Comment: console.log(global)

Comment: `app.set('config', config);` `app.get('config'); ` was a canonical express.js way